# How to get rid of getters and setters from the Netbeans Navigator window

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans

It is not uncommon to create many getters and setters in a Java class. In many of the circumstances, we don't really need them but have to create them due to the requirement of the Framework that we use (say for example in JSF managed bean).

The Netbeans Navigator window seems cluttered with these getters and setters and make it difficult to look for the methods we really have to work with.

Is there any way to make these getters and setters away from Netbeans Navigator window?

[image: Navigator window]

Comment: I think the best you can do is close them so all that's visible are the method signatures.

Comment: Another option is to put them all at the end of the class so that they don't clutter your eye-line.

Comment: I mean the Navigator window not the editing window.

Comment: I've updated my post with image

Comment: WHile I don't know how you would hide them in Netbeans, I wonder if you know about [project lombok](http://www.projectlombok.org) ? Here's a [cool example of what it can do](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html). That probably *should* hide it from Netbeans as well - though I have not tried it in Netbeans.

Comment: Wow, that definitely needs refactoring. It seems that you've mingled model(s) into the controller.

Comment: Good question. Seems that even in NetBeans 8 there is still no way to suppress the display of getter/setter accessor methods in the Navigator pane. Annoying.

Comment: I posted a feature request, [Bug # 248871](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248871).

Answer (score 1):

I often create a "boilerplate" superclass for junk like that (at least before Lombok, when I'm able to use Lombok). The methods are still accessible by viewing inherited properties.

That said, a class with this many properties might be due for some refactoring, depending on your actual needs--that's a lot to keep track of.

(You may also be able to filter the list, but that's risky, because if you hide, say, `get*` you might remove real methods from view.)

Comment: @MISS_DUKE I don't know, that's why I said "may" ;) I'm not very familiar with NetBeans.